# Entity framework 6.1.2 support for .NET framework 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, compatibility

My application was created in `.NET fx 4.5` and it was using `Entity Framework 6.1.2`.

I have just downgraded to .NET 4.0 as the server only has that for a maximum version. I don't have access to upgrade .NET framework version on server.

So, I have changed project properties to 4.0 and I am able to build.

Now my problem is, after deploying my application to the server, I'm getting the below error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions' from assembly 'mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TypeExtensions.Assembly(Type type)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.EnsureLoadedForContext(Type
>   contextType)     at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.InitializeLazyInternalContext(IInternalConnection
>   internalConnection, DbCompiledModel model)     at

It looks like this is due to a fx 4.0 compatibility issue.

Please guide how I could resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

If you use its NuGet package,

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework

Make sure after changing target framework version you uninstall and install it again. That forces NuGet to add the .NET 4.0 references to your project, instead of the .NET 4.5 ones.

Comment: I tried but, getting same error still. Please guide. It is console application and using class libarary as DAL project.

Comment: Do you have access to that server in order to check patching level? Even if you use .NET 4.0, there are several critical patches required in order to address issues, such as [KB2468871](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871)

Answer (score -2):

Sorry, .NET 4.0 is deprecated and you shouldn't be using it for any production work. Either downgrade to .NET 3.5 SP 1 or upgrade to 4.5.x.

Comment: we dont' have any control for produciton. But, please guide , how i could make compatiblle EF version for .NET FX 4.0 ?

Comment: It is just a reference issue. .NET 4.0 is still supported by EF 6.1.2.

Comment: .net 4.0 is deprecated? Could you please reference where did you get this information?

Comment: Correct reference should have been [this](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/framework_faq/en-us) as your own website is not a official channel of microsoft announcements. Anyway, what I understand is .net 4.0 will not be deprecated, only the runtime environment will not get security updates and other support. As they stated clearly, all the products built with .net 4.0 will run (at least expected to) without rebuild in .net 4.5 runtime environment. Correct me if I get this wrong.

Comment: "Will not get security updates and other support" is a pretty good definition of 'deprecated' in this context. As for running .NET 4.0 applications on .NET 4.5.x, that should work but there is a small chance that you'll hit a breaking change that actually matters. (It's not like 1.x to 2.0, where even DateTime was broke.)